# How to add postgre query parameter to FastReport?

Tags: postgresql, fastreport

I'm trying to integrate my reporting services using FastReport and my database are using Postgre. But I have problem with assigning query parameter into my custom query.

Here is how my query look like:

```sql
-- $1 = periode_from
-- $2 = periode_to
select
    (
        select
            web.get_periode(coalesce($1, '2023/01')) || ' - ' || web.get_periode(coalesce($2, '2023/12'))
    ) as periode,
    coalesce($1, '2023/01') as tahun,
    kl.value_1 jenis_kegiatan,
    (
        select
            count(1)
        from
            web.reg_tra_registrasi r
            join web.lay_tra_rad rad on rad.registrasi_id = r.id
            join web.set_mas_lab_rad_det_param dpa on dpa.set_mas_lab_rad_id = rad.id
            join web.set_mas_lab_rad ml on ml.id = dpa.set_mas_lab_rad_id
            join web.set_mas_gen g on g.id = ml.kelompok_id
        where
            g.id = kl.id
            and r.deleted_at is null
            and (
                r.is_cancel = false
                or null
            )
            and r.tgl_reg >= concat(coalesce($1, '2023/01'), '/01 00:00:00') :: timestamp
            and r.tgl_reg <= (
                (
                    date_trunc('month', date(coalesce($2, '2023/12') || '/01')) + interval '1 month - 1 day'
                ) || ' 23:59:59'
            ) :: timestamp
    ) jml
from
    web.reg_tra_registrasi r
    join web.lay_tra_rad t on t.registrasi_id = r.id
    join web.set_mas_lab_rad_det_param dp on dp.set_mas_lab_rad_id = t.id
    join web.set_mas_lab_rad l on l.id = dp.set_mas_lab_rad_id
    join web.set_mas_gen kl on kl.id = l.kelompok_id
    and r.deleted_at is null
    and (
        r.is_cancel = false
        or null
    )
    and r.tgl_reg >= concat(coalesce($1, '2023/01'), '/01 00:00:00') :: timestamp
    and r.tgl_reg <= (
        (
            date_trunc('month', date(coalesce($2, '2023/12') || '/01')) + interval '1 month - 1 day'
        ) || ' 23:59:59'
    ) :: timestamp
group by
    kl.id
order by
    kl.value_1;
```

That query passes when I press Next button in the Data Source Wizard so I declared them in the "Define Parameters" step as:

- `$1` with `DefaultValue` of `2023/04`
- `$2` with `DefaultValue` of `2023/05`

But as soon as I hit Preview button, it throws an error

```
bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 2
```

Referring to [this issue](https://github.com/FastReports/FastReport/issues/102), someone told us to use `@` symbol for parameter declaration but as soon as I changed `$1` into `@periode_from`, I got an error

```
42703: Column "periode_from" does not exists
```

What is the proper way to do this?